# python import vs from...import

Tags: python

Why do I have to do:

`from entertainment_website.models import Event`

instead of

`import entertainment_website.models.Event`

The 2nd one I get:

```
 ImportError: No module named Event
```

Comment: What is `Event`?  If it is a class inside the module `entertainment_website.models` than you can't import it as a module (using `import ...`).

Comment: You may find this enlightening: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Answer (score 4):

Because `Event` seems to not be an importable module / namespace but a class that is part of the former.

Answer (score 2):

`Event` is not a module, it's a class (well, I'm assuming a class by the naming convention).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the first one imports the class from a module. The second one imports a MODULE not a class.