# Confused on import syntax

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I was hoping someone could answer this. I am going through Mark Lutz's "Programming in Python".

If I issue the statement in an interactive session:

```
import tkinter
```

this statement works:

```
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename
```

However the same statements fail in a script with the error, "module has no attribute filedialog". I can get it to work if I type in the script:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

and then to use it just use "askopenfilename".

I am just trying to understand why it isn't working in the script. It was my understanding I could reference it through dotted notation, but either that isn't true or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: it works here. what versions are you using ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python import vs from...import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841452/python-import-vs-from-import)

Comment: Doesn't look like a dupe. The syntax in that thread is slightly different. Plus my question references a supplied module so it should be easier to relate to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that tkinter is a module and tkinter.filedialog is another module. So, since your code said "import tkinter" python only imports tkinter and not tkinter.filedialog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That certainly makes sense. Does the IDLE session have some extra logic then that is able to reference it?

Comment: @brianj The python IDLE is written in `Tkinter` itself. maybe that is what causes problems with the import.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes I did read that. Now that you pointed out that tkinter.filedialog is actually it's own module, I believe my question in answered. Thanks for the help!